# Assume that $f(x)\ge0$ if $x$ is a point in $\bf{I}$ with a rational component. Prove that $\int_{\bf{I}}f\ge0$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, integration, self-learning

Let **I** be a generalized rectangle in $\Bbb R^n$ and suppose the function $f:\bf{I}\to\Bbb R$ is Riemann integrable. Assume that $f(x)\ge0$ if $x$ is a point in $\bf{I}$ with a rational component. Prove that $\int_{\bf{I}}f\ge0$.

---

**My trails:**

Since $f$ is integrable, for each positive number $\epsilon$, there is a partition $\bf{P}$ of $\ \bf{I}$ such that $$U(f,P)-L(f,P)<\epsilon$$

We know that by a lemma, there exist $m, M$ $\ \forall \in \bf{I}$ such that $$m\ vol\ I \le L(f,P)\le U(f,P)\le M vol I $$

Since $f\ge 0$, then  $\ \ m, M\ge 0$

So, $U(f,P)-L(f,P)\ge 0$ so, $\int f\ge 0$

---

I guess, there are many mistakes and drawbacks. Please can somebody completedi these by writing above answer part step by step and clearly ? By the way, this is self-studying, not homework, Thanks :)

Comment: It would be easier if you provided the definitions behind $U$, $ L$, etc. Not everyone is familiar with this notation.

Comment: I just have been learning this topic by myself.  Please can you show me this proof step by step only one time. I want to learn. Please:) @TZakrevskiy

Comment: Could you define $vol$?

Comment: I wrote nonsense, I guess. TZakrevskiy's solution is enough and simple, I think. Is it? @AnonSubmitter85 thus, this is not necessary to correct my proof. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you apply the property that integration is a monotone operation? If $f\ge g$, then $\int_I f \ge \int_I g$, which gives the answer for your question with $g=0$.

**Edit**

I think it's better to prove that the integral of a positive function is positive, because the monotonicity of integration is based on this fact, hence my previous proposition was, in fact, circular.

Here's what we can do:
Riemann integration is equiavalent to Darboux integration (see [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux_sum)), on a side note, I found where the $U-L$ notation comes from, so we can write (in 1-D for the sake of simplicity) for a partition $P$
$$M_i=\sup _{[x_i,x_{i+1})}f(x),$$
$$U(f,P)=\sum_i M_i(x_{i+1}-x_i),$$
$$U_f =\inf_P U(f,P).$$
Note that $M_i\ge 0$, because for any partition $P$ each interval in this partition is bound to contain a point with rational coordinates.

In the same spirit we define $m_i$, $L(f,P)$, and $L_f$.

Clearly, the quantities $U(f,P)$ are positive, thus $U_f\ge 0$. The integrability of $f$ is defined by the equality $U_f=L_f=\int_I f$, hence we can conclude.

Comment: That's, $g=0$ since $f\ge 0$ and $\int_{I}g=0$, we can say that $\int_{I}f\ge 0$. Is it? Enough? Thanks:)

Comment: @B11b In fact, it is not enough, because we prove monotonicity using the fact that integral of a positive function is positive. See incoming edit.

Comment: Monotonicity? I dont know how to proof:( please I am glad you to add this part:( I want to learn properly:)

Comment: The question says that $f(x)\ge 0$ as long as some component of $x$ is in $\mathbb{Q}$, so how can you say that $f \ge g$ with $g=0$? What if $f(x) = -\infty$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \mathbb{Q}^n$? Don't you need to use the fact that $f$ is Riemann integrable somewhere?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write $n=1$ @AnonSubmitter85

Comment: I editted. Sorry..

Comment: Okay I got it well now:) thank you for your understanble explanation :)

Comment: Don't you need the density of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ to show that $\inf_{P} U \ge 0$? Given the problem statement, $f$ may be less than zero for $x \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \mathbb{Q}^n$.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 each term in the sum for $U(f,P)$ is non-negative, hence $U(f,P)$ is non-negative aswell. When I take an infimum of set of non-negative entities, I obtain a non-negative number. Don't see where the density of $\mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb R$ comes into play.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy The example I gave is not applicable since it is not Riemann integrable ($\sup L \neq \inf U$), but I think that it is your answer is missing, viz. proof that $f$ is non-negative. Since it is given that $f$ is Riemann integrable, we know that $\sup L = \int f = \inf U \Rightarrow 0 \leq \sup L$. If $f(x) < 0$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \mathbb{Q}^n$, this would not hold. Thus, $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. It just seems important since $f$ was said to be nonnegative only for $x$ "with a rational component."

Answer (score 1):

It is given that $f(x) \ge 0$ only for $x \in I$ such that $x$ has a rational component, so we can't just assume that $f$ is a nonnegative function, because there exists $x\in I$ such that $x \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \mathbb{Q}^n$. Rather, we need to show it. Since it is also given that $f$ is Riemann integrable, we have, by definition, that for all partitions $P$

$$
\sup_P L = \int_I f = \inf_P U
$$

Since $f(x) \geq 0$ for $x \in I$ with a rational component and the rationals are dense in $\mathbb{R}$, for any interval $\left[p_{i-1},p_i\right]$ of any partition $P=\{p_1,\dots,p_n\}$ such that $\Delta p_i = p_i - p_{i-1} > 0$, we have

$$
\sup_{x\in\left[p_{i-1},p_i\right]} f(x) \geq 0
$$

Thus, $\inf_{P} U \geq 0$, which then implies that $\int_I f \geq 0$ since $\int_I f = \inf_{P} U$.